# How to disable Linux Image and Header Updates?

Tags: kernel, updates, xubuntu, linux-headers, amdgpu-pro

I'm running an Ethereum mining rig on Xubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS).
With this, I have been running the latest AMD Blockchain GPU drivers and ROCM kernel.
I had 4 GPUs running at 29 M/H, but upon rebooting my system these dropped to 23 M/H. Initially I thought this was an issue with my AMD drivers, and tried a fresh installation of everything.
However, it appears to have been caused by an update to linux image and headers to version 4.13.0-26.
Running the following commands resolved the issue:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic
sudo apt remove linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic
reboot
```

My question: Is there a way to avoid these updating again while still being able to run other general package updates?

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

`linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` are dummy (empty) packages, which depends on the most recently released kernel package.

After that, you will not get a kernel update.

Comment: Add `linux-headers-generic` to prevent its upgrades.